How to use ASE to combine several MD trajectories into 1 trajectory
I have several continuous MD trajectories. How can I combine them into one trajectory to summarize all?

Which program did you use to run the MD? NAMD and GROMACS have their own "combinator".

You can combine trajectories simply by:
from ase.io import read, write

all_trajs = []
for traj_fname in traj_fnames:
    all_trajs += read(traj_fname, index=':')
write('all_trajs.traj', all_trajs)

